# How to add expose View filter for a derived field

Tags: views

I have a Drupal View looking at User profiles. One of the fields is derived, or calculated, which is done using Views PHP.

I'm trying to add an exposed filter for this View, but the expose option isn't visible.

Is there another module I use to add this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I needed to filter the results myself in the Views alter hook.

Results Alter,
https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7

Query Alter
https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7

Comment: This does not answer the question, can you elaborate the answer with steps.

Comment: I've added the hyperlinks.